# Shrinkwrapping floating divs of variable number, width, and height inside another div

Tags: css, html

In order to achieve matching heights of various divs of variable number, width, and height, I am using a jQuery script that requires those divs to be floating.  However, I would like them centered, so I am using the relative position trick to center them.

**CSS**

```
div#cardwrap {
border:3px purple solid;
float:left;
position: relative;
left:50%;
}

div#centermaster {
text-align:center;
border:1px yellow solid;
float:left;
position: relative;
left:-50%;
}

div.cardtable {
float:left;
padding:35px;
border:1px green solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=cardwrap>
    <div id=centermaster>
        <div class=cardtable>Images</div> (variable number)
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This would work perfectly, except that I can't seem to get the wrapper to shrinkwrap correctly.  Before the images load, it looks fine [initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBQMH.jpg) - the yellow wrapper is centering the green divs.  But as the images load, the green divs wrap to the next line, which I *do* want.  But then, a [gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek6Fy.jpg) appears on the right so that the yellow div is no longer shrinkwrapping, and thus, not centering, them.  How can I maintain the yellow div matching the width of however many green divs can fit on a row?

Another method to equalize div heights while centering them is also welcome.

(Also are there scripts to equalize widths of certain div class, given variable content?)  Basically, the end goal is center the green divs into a table-like format, while accommodating for both variable screen sizes and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly do you want, but I think, that you need inline-blocks here, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TSpXZ/

To make them work in IE, add the following in the Conditional Comments:

```
div.cardtable {
    display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
```

And try to experiment more with inline-blocks — they are awesome!

Comment: Oh!  I started with inline blocks, but I didn't use "vertical-align:top;".  This gives me the behavior I was struggling with!  However, my friend, whom I'm helping with this puzzle, reminded me that if we have borders on cardtable at the end, that would look best if the heights were the same (as currently happens after the jQuery script).  However, if I don't get an answer to my question about the gap, I may just come back and accept this answer.  Thanks for the suggestion (and even including the IE conditional)!